# REGEX for 4 decimal places

Tags: regular-expressions

I want REGEX to allow only 4 decimal places no more and no digits. Requirement is at least 1 decimal and up to 4.

This is what i have:

```
REGEX(TEXT(Won_Lost_By_How_Much__c),"\\.[0-9][0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?")
```

It allows 1.99999 though.

Comment: for general programming/Regex questions [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/) may be more appropriate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

REGEX returns *true* when the pattern matches. Validation rules need *true* when the validation rule should trigger. As such, you need to invert the result with NOT. Also, I would expect there to always be a leading 0, so you'll need to account for that:

```
NOT(REGEX(TEXT(Won_Lost_By_How_Much__c),"^0?\\.\\d{1,4}$"))
```

Comment: Awesome thanks, I should have realized the NOT() requirement, but appreciate the help